# Why use "s = --size" instead of "s = size"?

Tags: java, data-structures

Code from PriorityQueue:

```
private E removeAt(int i) {
    assert i >= 0 && i < size;
    modCount++;
    int s = --size;        //    <- Why???
    if (s == i) // removed last element
        queue[i] = null;
    else {
        E moved = (E) queue[s];
        queue[s] = null;
        siftDown(i, moved);
        if (queue[i] == moved) {
            siftUp(i, moved);
            if (queue[i] != moved)
                return moved;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

What's differences between `s = --size` and `s = size`? Anybody could help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'd need to add in another line after it to do `size = size - 1` or `size--`

Comment: I was a bit confused by this question, until it occurred to me that the OP probably thought -- quite reasonably -- that `--size ` is equivalent to `-(-size) `, which would of course be the same as just `size`. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int s = --size;` is a [*pre*-decrement operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators), and that is not equivalent to `int s = size;`. It is equivalent to

```
int s = (size = (size - 1));
```

**or**

```
size = size - 1;
int s = size;
```

But it is *shorter* than both of those.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `s = size`, then you need to add line `size = size - 1`. As you have to decrease the queue size after removal of an element.

Answer (score 0):

PriorityQueue is based on array `private transient Object[] queue;`. In PriorityQueue this array stores data of binary heap. `removeAt(int)` is an operation on removing an element from heap. You remove element from heap by taking **the last** element of the heap (here you use `int s = --size` to assign to s the index of last element; alternatively you can do `int s = heap.length - 1`). 
Then delete the element you want `queue[s] = null;` and do work to fill the gap in array with sifting operations `siftDown`, `siftUp`.

Answer (score 0):

`a = i++`  means `a = i ; i = i + 1`

`a = ++i`  means `i = i + 1 ; a = i ;`

the same to minus